# DLink DCS-3220 network camera suddenly fails to display image

Tags: windows-7, activex, ip-camera

I have been using a D-Link DCS-3220 camera for several years.  It suddenly will not display  an image.  I am able to capture a snapshot without issue.  Access is on local network, not from Internet.

I am thinking a recent Windows Update made some sort of change but no luck in finding that change.

System is Windows 7 x64 with IE 11

IE is configured to allow Active-X and I have tested with Symantec Endpoint Protection disabled.

I have also tried using Chrome with same result.  I have tested with two other Windows 7 systems (x86) that previously worked but now fail.

Camera has been reset to factory but there was no change in behavior.

Nothing in Windows event logs

Application iSpy can still access a video stream from the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

Oddly, D-Link states that some cameras are not compatible with IE 11 but this DCS-3220 had worked well with IE 11 up to an update.

Some on a [D-Link Forum](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=58397.0)  suggested [Java update](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=57476.0) was a problem but making the suggested changes had no effect.

The forum also suggested [Compatibility mode](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=58272.0) and that was the direction needed.  Changing to compatibility mode resulted in a prompt to install the add-on MFCActive-X control. Once installed, video again displays.

Comment: Tested for almost a week and camera works a treat again.

Answer (score 0):

It probably uses a plugin and Google Chrome, at least, has disabled plugins. You can still temporarily enable plugins until they soon take that option away. In Chrome, go here: chrome://flags/#enable-npapi and enable NPAPI and restart Chrome.

If the camera still doesn't work, next time buy Hikvision from an authorized distributor (not online) or security dealer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the change to allow NPAPI made no change in the issue